# wpdb Custom Meta Data with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, wpdb

This is one of those problems that I've spent way too much time on, and there is probably a VERY simple solution that I am missing.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to populate a select box with names from custom data (`meta_key` "`pyd_pub_author`").  But, I cant just call the data directly, because it also needs to make sure that, meta_key `"pyd_pub_type" = "Newsletter"`

The `meta_value` for `meta_key "pyd_pub_type"` needs to be `"Newsletter"` and the author names needs to come from meta_key "`pyd_pub_author`".  The tricky part is, there are many other "`pyd_pub_authors`" that are associated with other "`pyd_pub_type`", I need to filter them out as well.

So, I need to filter out the meta_value "`Newsletter`" and all "`pyd_pub_author`" that are associated with it.

What I've done is this:

```
 $metakey       = $prefix . 'pub_author';
    $authors_query = $wpdb->get_col(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value, post_id
             FROM $wpdb->postmeta
             WHERE meta_key = %s
             HAVING post_id = ANY (
             SELECT DISTINCT post_id
             FROM $wpdb->postmeta
             WHERE meta_value = 'Newsletter'
             )
            ", $metakey
        )
    );
```

This returns the name of an author for each of the post_id(s) that match the list, even if they are duplicate.  The "DISTINCT" isnt filtering the names because it is checking the post_id.
So, what this leaves me to to is run an array_unique() to strip out the duplicates.  It works, but there has to be an easier, less expensive way to do this.

head->desk, head->desk, head->desk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error in the above query.  There still may be a better way to do this, thank you kaiser, and I will update once I've done more study.  What I forgot to do was GROUP_CONCAT another meta_value so i could pull out different bits.  It still seems longer than it needs to be, but it gets the job done fast.  Here is the code, just wrap this in a form and select and you can have a drop down of unique meta_values with a few filters.

```
    $metakey       = $prefix . 'pub_author';
    $authors_query = $wpdb->get_col(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT meta_value, post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value)
                             FROM pyd_postmeta
                             WHERE meta_key = %s
                             GROUP BY meta_value
                             HAVING post_id = ANY (
                             SELECT post_id
                             FROM pyd_postmeta
                             WHERE meta_value = 'Newsletter'
                             )
            ", $metakey
        )
    );

    if ( $authors_query ) {
        foreach ( $authors_query as $author ) {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $author ?>" <?php selected( $pydnet_show_author, $author ) ?> ><?php echo $author ?></option>';
        <?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please mark this as solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `posts_clauses` filter to intercept the query and change whatever you need. It also gives you *imho* better insights **about the whole query parts** and an easier way to debug.

```
function debug_query( $pieces )
{
    $dump  = '<pre>';
    $dump .= var_export( $pieces, FALSE );
    $dump .= '</pre>';

    echo $dump;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'debug_query' );
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't used 'posts_clauses' before, I will read up on it.  After a night of sleep, i found my mistake.  I will post it below.