# Order by custom field meta_key date and then by custom file meta_key number

Tags: custom-post-types, order

I'm trying do order a custom post type page by 2 variables:
- first is the custom post type meta_key "date"
- then, for posts with the same date, it should be ordered by meta_key "number"

I'm willing to set for some kind of ordering on the second level but right now it really seems random:

```
 <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                              'post_type' => 'product', 
                              'meta_query' => array(
                                          array(
                                                  'key' => 'options_type',
                                                  'value' => 'Denim'
                                                  ),
                                      ),
                               'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
                               'meta_key' => 'options_date',
                               'posts_per_page' => 50 ,
                               'order'    => 'DESC'


                              )); ?>
```

Even editing the "wordpress publication date" doesn't affect the "same day" order. So I end up with:

- 09.03.2012 244 Diesel (wordpress date 3.8.2012)
- 09.03.2012 246 Levi's (wordpress date 3.9.2012)
- 09.03.2012 247 Evisu (wordpress date 3.10.2012)

(i'm using european date displayng, so 09.03 means March, 9th)

---

### edit

just to clarify:
I've some custom field and i've set a specific options_date field for the custom post type, which is different from the wordpress date.

I would like to order the posts using a multiple order: custom field "options_date" and, inside the same "options_date" by another custom field "options_info".

ordering with

```
'orderby'  => 'meta_value date',
```

doesn't seem to work and it's not the target result, I'm looking for a multiple meta_key ordering.

Comment: Try to add **both** meta values that you want to `orderby` into the value and separate them with a space.

Comment: with `'meta_key' => 'options_date options_number',` I get nothing in return. the site is not broken, but no posts appear.

Comment: Please re-read my comment. I said if you want to orderby 2 values, then you'll have to add both to `orderby`. So `'orderby' => 'date meta_value'` would be what I suggested.

Comment: Ups, sorry. Almost there... Now inside the same "option_date" the order is correct (wordpress date), but the ASC/DESC seems to control just the second ordering, the first on is always ASC (older option_date post apper first).

Comment: Update your question with the output from [this answers code](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44904/385).

Comment: forgive me if I'm a little slow: where am I supposed to put the code from your answer code to make it work?

Comment: functions.php. And wrap the `add_action`  in another function that gets added with the `init` hook.

Comment: huh... don't know what `add_action` do you refer to. and honestly don't know how to wrap something in another function to hook with `init`. copy/paste that code into functions.php makes all site "404 not found".