# Can I use OR relation for one item when calling tax_query from WP_Query and use AND for the rest?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I am trying to refine search in wordpress template. Basically I want to use multiselect with . I am using array to store selected options like this: location[]=term1&location[]=term2 etc etc. This is how the search code looked:

```
    $form_location = $_GET['location'];

    if ($form_location != "")
    $form_location = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'location',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $form_location
    ); 

    // Final Query
    $items_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listings',
        'meta_query' => array(
            $form_price,
            $form_area_range,
            $rentbuy
        ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            $form_location,
            $form_property_type,
            $form_rating,
            $form_bed,
            $form_bath
        )
    );
    ?>
    <?php $items_args = new WP_Query($items_args); if ( $items_args->have_posts() ) :
```

...

I modified $location to handle array. I didn't quite done the loop right because I am not sure how to handle tax_query. Here is what I did. I added foreach:

```
        foreach ($form_location as $loc2) {
        $form_location = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $loc2
        ); }
```

This is the output I cached:

```
WP_Query Object ( [query_vars] => Array ( [post_type] => listings [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Array ( [key] => rentbuy [value] => rent ) ) [tax_query] => Array ( [relation] => AND [0] => Array ( [taxonomy] => location [field] => slug [terms] => term1 ) [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => )...
```

Here is the thing, I want the location taxonomy to be used for a query with OR condition for every item from Array it got, and others from tax_query with AND. Is this possible and how? Google is not friendly tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible per default. Your best bet is the [`posts_clauses`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6d97f53134984f9a45625cfc01c9db257918f5dc/wp-includes/query.php#L2850) filter. The answers on the site [provide plenty examples](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=posts_clauses) for that filter. You might also want to look into using the `posts_search` filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I am looking into posts_clauses I stumbled upon a code which is supposed to "give you better insights about the whole query parts and an easier way to debug." The code which I found here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/44904/40782. However when I add it this is what I get http://pastie.org/8422891, without any search results (there are if I remove the filter).

Comment: I forgot to add return, it shows search results but there seems to be not much in this dump where I can define OR for what I need it

Comment: @user130888 See update